# Webservice with pagination but don't show row number

Tags: sql-server, pagination

So I have this webservice that makes an sql sorta query like this:

```
declare @pagerows int select @pagerows = 5
declare @pageindex int select @pageindex = 1 

select * from (select ROW_NUMBER() over(order by lm.PostNr, lm.Adress) Row, lm.Adress, lm.PostNr, p.CityName, e.DepartmentName, lm.Adress + ', ' + lm.PostNr + ', ' + p.CityName as FullAdress 
from Housing lm 
inner join Department e on lm.HeadNr = e.HeadNr and lm.DepartmentNr = e.DepartmentNr 
inner join PostNr p on lm.PostNr = p.PostNr 
where lm.Types in (31, 32, 33) and lm.Adress like 'whatever%'
group by lm.Adress, lm.PostNr, p.CityName, e.DepartmentName) a
where Row between(@pageRows* @pageindex) -@pageRows + 1 and(@pageRows * @pageindex)
```

Now I don't actually want to have the rownumber in my output but I'm not sure how to remove it and still have the pagination work.

Basically how do I remove the `ROW_NUMBER() over(order by lm.PostNr, lm.Adress) Row,` part from the select statement but still keep the pagination working?

Comment: that is required for the pagination to work. You want to remove the `Row` from the result is it ? Just don't include in the `SELECT` clause and please please don't use `SELECT *`, change to specify only the column that you required in the result

Comment: Oh jeez I get it now that was way simpler than I made it up in my mind to be. Thank you.